# Java EE Servlet as container for XMPP connector

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, xmpp

I'm writing my first Java EE 5 app on WebLogic 10.3.5. and need some architectural advice.

When the app starts I need to open a persistent connection to an XMPP server to send Instant Messages.  Messages will be constantly pulled from a table, which will be populated by another part of the app.

As I see it I can't use container managed objects for this, such as EJB, because I would then have no control over the object and socket connection lifecycle.

Is a Servlet an appropriate candidate for a process that starts with the app and holds a persistent socket connection?

Comment: Persistent connections (sometimes called keep-alive connections) can be established using servlet, here is the some resources i used : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-keepalive.html , i hope it helps.

Comment: why not use `@Singleton` `@Startup` EJB with `@PostConstruct` to open connection and `@PreDestroy` to close it?

Comment: Ah sorry, you are on JEE5 -- so the above is not completely true

Comment: That was my understanding, tair.  Does anybody know if it is possible to have a singleton startup with the app on Java EE 5?

Comment: Am I correct in saying that a Stateless Session Bean is not a good candidate for a establishing persistent TCP connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating a ServletContextListener that instantiates and EJB 3.0 stateless session bean.

The session bean then instantiates an XMPP connection using a @PostConstruct method and closes the connection using a @PreDestroy method.

I made the session bean use an EJB 3.0 Timer to poll the message queue table every couple of minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are going to use one of the options listed by Markus Eisele in his [blogpost](http://blog.eisele.net/2010/12/seven-ways-to-get-things-started-java.html). There is a mention of Weblogic-specific mechanism (which is not pure Java EE however) for application lifecycle listeners.

Comment: Thanks Tair.  I just discovered the ServletContextListener and that seems to be working.